# Slow Loop Execution In VB.NET 2003

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I fill data in `C1FLEXGRID` from `DataTable` using `for...each` loop with `DataRow` and `DataRowCollection` but it gives output very slow. How can I solve it.

Comment: How slow is too slow? How many rows are you dealing with? How long does it take? and . . . WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING?

Comment: TIME INCREASE AS PER NO.OF RECORD INCREASE E.G. IT TAKE 5 SEC. FOR 100 ROWS AND 12 SEC. FOR 250 ROWS

Comment: YOUR CAPS KEY IS BROKEN, GITS

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried switching off drawing while adding the rows?

```
grid.redraw = False

// Add rows here

grid.redraw = True
```